# Strange behavior of the explorer.exe process

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Something happened, and now the **explorer.exe** is acting strange. For example, I have a **mirc.exe** startup when the system boots. Window with this program immediately freezes. Also icons in the tray do not change their state.

[image: bug image]

P.S. I tried to reboot my PC and shutdown him.

P.S.S. It's interesting that the safest mode looks good.

P.S.S.S. Problem solved. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What exactly happened?  Have you tried to reinstall the application?

Comment: Do you have a system restore point?  You may want to revert back to that point.

Comment: @Ramhound, Unfortunately, I do not know what happened.

Comment: @rrirower, Unfortunately, I do not remember a restore point is created or not.

Comment: You can check by going into Control Panel/System and Security/System.  Then select System Protection.  A dialog will display that you can try a system restore if one is available.  Be careful though, you may revert other changes also.

Comment: @rrirower, I click on this link, but the dialog does not open.

Comment: Turns out provided information does not accurately explain OPs problem - freezing problem is much more general. VTC as duplicate.  If you'd like it reopened please edit your question and add more specific information, including what you've tried already and what the results were. Use the marked dupe as a guide to methods.

Comment: Also see: [How to diagnose computer lockups and freezes?](http://superuser.com/questions/220678/how-to-diagnose-computer-lockups-and-freezes?rq=1), and [windows 7 fast in safe mode but extremely slow in normal mode](http://superuser.com/questions/427019/windows-7-fast-in-safe-mode-but-extremely-slow-in-normal-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we were unable to find the source of the problem. I restored the system from 13 September. Yesterday I installed postgresql, 0xDBE and PremiumSoft Navicat Premium 10.1.6. It is possible that the problem is somewhere here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your picture it looks like mIRC is freezing while waiting for a network connection (judging by the fact your network icon has the busy spinner).

If mIRC is set to start with Windows, it may be starting faster than your network connection does.

Fix your network/Internet connection and the freezing should stop.

If it *is* just a timing thing, then use a scheduled task or a batch file to start mIRC, so that you can add a delay before it starts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're wrong. My internet speed is 30 Mbps. The speed of my Internet has not changed over the last few days.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it has anything to do with the speed of your Internet, it has to do with how long it takes (after boot) for your network connection to become available. In your provided picture the network icon in the taskbar shows that it's "Busy" which means it is trying to establish a network connection. Until it establishes a working network connection, mIRC is going sit there trying to contact the IRC server until it either does, or finally gives up.

Comment: Iternete icon is really busy. But this is only an example. The whole system is lag and it is not responding.

Comment: @denis Since we're not psychics, you should mention things like that in your original question, as well as what steps you've taken already in attempts to rectify the problem.