# Windows Service causing low performance?

Tags: windows, performance, windows-services

I never had issues with my laptop performance till some windows 8.1 updates earlier this week. 
At first, I thought it might be some malware, so I run all kind of tools and scans (it took me a really long time), but no issues were found and the laptop was showing an extremely bad performance: folders, programs and websites taking several minutes to load, as if I/O operations had slowed down by 20x, Chrome saying "waiting cache..." Then I went for a system restore, which fixed other kind of issues in the past, but for some reason I had a single restoration point and the rollback didnt solve the issue.

Then I came across this question:
[windows 7 fast in safe mode but extremely slow in normal mode](https://superuser.com/questions/427019/windows-7-fast-in-safe-mode-but-extremely-slow-in-normal-mode)

Exactly my problem, in safe mode, I'm able to use everything normally (but laptop overheats a lot, so its a temp workaround to be avoided)! Then following the advice there, I tried to restart in debug mode, and progressively turn on different services, but as someone suggested, MS isnt likely to be the one causing the issue, so I selected all the Windows services and I turned all of them on... Guess what, the problem is back again.

So now my question is, how do I find which service is causing the issue so that I can disable it? There are several to go for the trial-error approach, and many of them have dependencies to each other...

Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows *Task Manager* to find out how CPU time is being used, if that is an issue.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*.
- Click on the *Details* tab.
- Click on the *CPU* header to sort by amount of time being used.

[image: Task Manager Details]

- Usually, *Services* run under *svchost.exe*, and there are many instances running simultaneously. Find the Process ID (PID) of the offender, in this example, *1808*.

[image: Task Manager Services]

- Click on the *Services* tab.
- Click on the *PID* header to sort by the ID.
- In this example, regrettably, there are *three Services* running under that ID, but at least this narrows the issue down to one of those. Turn off *one at a time* to find the culprit.

Microsoft's (Sysinternals') [*Process Explorer* (PE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) would give additional information. In particular, if the issue is due to excessive disk IO, PE can display disk IO information.

Comment: When checking the CPU usage (I was exceptic about it since the values often seem to be quite weird, ie. why there's always so much idle CPU?), I realized the guilty of the slow system was Microsoft Windows Defender Antispyware (MSMpEng.exe) with an average usage of 13-20%, which doesn't sound like a lot to me, as allegedly there's almost another 85% left... But since it may monitor resources and files, might become a bottle neck tho. I´ve disabled it and I managed to start the system quite smoothly, not sure if as much as prior to this issue, but we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Services may also use more memory and it causes slowing Chrome which also need more RAM. To filter the services with respect to memory usage use the following command with [`tasklist`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist):

```
TaskList /SVC /FI "memusage gt 12345" /FI "imagename eq svchost.exe"
```

What doest the command do? In words, this command shows all the Services (`/svc`), then filter out (`/fi`) the processes with executable name `svchost.exe` and with memory usage greater than 12345. Change this memory usage upper limit as you want.  To understand the full command, separate the long command in pieces:

- `TaskList /SVC`: Show all the services
- `/FI "memusage gt 12345"`: Filter out the processes with memory usage greater than 12345.
- `/FI "imagename eq svchost.exe"`: Filter out the processes with executable name `svchost.exe`.

The output will be something like this:

```
Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ============================================
svchost.exe                    772 BrokerInfrastructure, DcomLaunch,
                               SystemEventsBroker
svchost.exe                   1412 BFE, mpssvc
svchost.exe                   1612 Winmgmt
```

There may be more than one service in one `svchost.exe` process. From Windows 10 Creators Update, if machine [has more than 3.5 GB RAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/svchost-service-refactoring#separating-svchost-services) each service will have it's separate process.